# Linguagem de marcação equivalente ao HTML?

Tags: html, linguagem-de-marcação

Apenas à titulo de curiosidade, andei pesquisando sobre  e não encontrei absolutamente nada relacionado.

O HTML é uma linguagem de marcação de texto, e existem outras como XML que é a única com uma explicação clara que encontrei, mas nunca vi/não achei outras coisas que possam utilizar de outras linguagens de marcação.

Existe outra linguagem de marcação que seja amplamente usada 
Se não, por que não existe outra linguagem tão difundida?
Se sim, quais são as principais linguagens? Existe alguma que na teoria poderia ser *melhor* que o HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML é uma variação do XML (na verdade isso mudou um pouco, acabou que o XHTML é que ficou assim). Como o nome dela diz (XML), é uma linguagem de marcação extensível, portanto tem uma ideia básica de como a linguagem de marcação deve ser, mas as *tags* específicas podem ser criadas conforme a necessidade nas suas derivadas.

Não é que XHTML seja XML, mas parte de uma base comum para sua criação. Vivem criando novas linguagens de marcação, nem todas usam essa base do XML.

Muitas pessoas consideram essa forma um pouco burocrática e verbosa de criar uma declaração. Alguns acham que não é poderosa o suficiente para identificar todas situações.

Muitas tecnologias de GUI, ORM, banco de dados, ou coisas específicas de troca de informações entre agentes usam uma variação do XML.

Não há nada que tenha exatamente a mesma função que o HTML que é a linguagem padronizada para escrever páginas web. Poderiam fazer algo bem melhor, provavelmente nem baseada em XML. Eu conheço uma pessoa que bolou algo bem mais interessante, mas a chance de ver isso implementado e adotado universalmente é zero :)

Não teria porque existir mais de uma linguagem padrão. Embora eu ache que deveria criar outra bem melhor pra substituir o HTML.

Difusão depende do ponto de vista. O fato de uma pessoa não saber não quer dizer que ela não é difundida. Mas o HTML é tão conhecido por ser algo usado em tecnologia muito difundida, ele pegou carona. E existe uma coisa de moda fazer a moda ser mais moda. Tem gente que desenvolve pra web porque sabe desenvolver pra web. Aí como muita gente faz pra web, tem gente que acha que só deve fazer pra web. E fazer pra web é usar HTML.

Curiosamente o XML surgiu depois do HTML quando perceberam que aquilo poderia ser uma generalização do HTML.

- [Lista da linguagens baseadas em XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_markup_languages).
- [Lista de linguagens de marcação para documentos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_document_markup_languages).
- [Lista de linguagens de marcação propósito geral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_markup_language).
- [Lista de linguagens para interface de usuário](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_user_interface_markup_languages).
- [Lista de linguagens para formatos gráficos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats#Vector_formats).
- [Lista de linguagens de conteúdo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_syndication_markup_languages).
- [Lista de linguagens em formato alternativo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 9):

Existem várias outras linguagens de marcação que são utilizadas em outros ambientes e contextos que não o web.

Um grande exemplo é a linguagem [XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295302.aspx), uma linguagem de marcação baseada em XML criada e mantida pela Microsoft. XAML é utilizada em vários produtos da Microsoft, como por exemplo, o framework [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/).

Existem algumas alternativas ao HTML, mas que no final serão "transpiladas" para HTML, afinal, o navegador não sabe interpretar essas outras linguagens. Um exemplo é a linguagem [Haml](http://haml.info/). Ser melhor ou pior é uma questão de gosto.