# É possível aplicar estilo a uma estrutura XML?

Tags: html, xml

A um tempo atrás fiz [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227443/linguagem-de-marca%C3%A7%C3%A3o-equivalente-ao-html), e esses dias pensei se eu não poderia usar XML para estruturas, por exemplo, com uma tabela,fazer com que os dois codigos a seguir tenham o mesmo comportamento ao serem interpretados pelo browser:

**XML:**

```
<root>
    <row>
        <col>col 1</col>
        <col>col 2</col>
        <col>col 3</col>
        <col>col 4</col>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col>col 1</col>
        <col>col 2</col>
        <col>col 3</col>
        <col>col 4</col>
    </row>
</root>
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>col 1</td>
        <td>col 2</td>
        <td>col 3</td>
        <td>col 4</td>
    </row>
    <tr>
        <td>col 1</td>
        <td>col 2</td>
        <td>col 3</td>
        <td>col 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

- É possível fazer isso ?
- Se sim, como?

OBS: Não tem nenhum contexto pra inserir isto, é apenas curiosidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim você pode indicar o estilo através de :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
```

Ou ainda:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="#style" type="text/css"?>
<root>
    <extras id="style">
    row{font-size: x-large;  color: #777777;}
    extras{ display: none; }
    </extras>
    <row>
        <col>col 1</col>
        <col>col 2</col>
        <col>col 3</col>
        <col>col 4</col>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col>col 1</col>
        <col>col 2</col>
        <col>col 3</col>
        <col>col 4</col>
    </row>
</root>
```

[Fonte](https://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html)